# Configure serverless.yml to have different settings based on Table name

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm using AWS Lambdas enabled by Serverless framework with DynamoDB as my primary DB.

Now, out table nomenclature is dependent on the stage to which we deploy our functions to.

For example,

for `prod` : `prod-primary`

for `test` : `test-primary`

for `local` : `local-primary`

In the table we also have 4-5 GSIs.

For our production table, we want to use **DynamoDB On-Demand**.

But for my testing table on which only I am testing, I would rather like to use **ProvisionedCapacity** setting to save unnecessary testing costs.

Right now, my table config looks like this :

```
Resources:
  myData:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: "${opt:stage, 'local'}-primary"
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: PK
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: SK
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: AK
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: createdBy
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: itemType
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: itemStatus
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: PK
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: SK
          KeyType: RANGE
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      StreamSpecification:
        StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: SK-PK-Index
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: SK
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: PK
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
        - IndexName: itemType-AK-index
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: itemType
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: AK
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
        - IndexName: createdBy-itemType-index
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: createdBy
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: itemType
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: expireAt
        Enabled: true
```

This works fine when I need to deploy to `prod` stage. However, I have to manually replace `BillingMode` with :

```
ProvisionedThroughput:
 ReadCapacityUnits: 1
 WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

And also add this under all the mentioned GSIs. Is there a way to automate this?